# My python code terminating with lack in memory due to large number of rows in files,

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following python code. The idea is to compare two tables which has two columns in each. Each row in both table represent an object. My task is to find the objects closest to each other present in both the tables. For this I am using a simple relation to find the distance between the objects (as mentioned in the code).

The main problem in this code is that, one table has 500k rows and the other 1.3 million rows. As I am running the code, the code terminates because of the huge size files I am importing. Is there any way to run the code faster or any way which I should follow to make this job done?

the code:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import sys
import string

out1= open('tab1_tab2_match.dat' ,'w')
out1.write (str(col1)+' '+str(col2)+' '+str(col1_1)+' '+str(col2_1)+' \n')

table = Table.read("tab1.dat",format="ascii")
item = list(table)

table1 = Table.read("tab2.dat",format="ascii")
item1 = list(table1)

for i in range(len(table)): 
    col1=item[i][0];col2=item[i][1];  
    for j in range(len(table1)): 
        col1_1=item1[j][0];col2_1=item1[j][1]
        del1=abs(col1-col1_1) ; del2=abs(col2-col2_1)
        d = ma.sqrt((del1*ma.cos(ma.radians(col2)))**2 + (del2**2)) 
        if (d <= 0.00008333): 
            print d
            print col1, col2, col1_1, col2_1
            out1.write (str(col1)+' '+str(col2)+' '+str(col1_1)+' '+str(col2_1)+'  \n') 

out1.close()
```

Comment: What are "lakh rows"?

Comment: @Nico 1 lakh = 100 000.

Comment: Do you really need to convert the tables to lists? I'm not familiar with astropy but I'd expect anything named `Table` to be efficient for data storage.

Comment: How big are the files in size? a million rows doesn't sound that big that it would use all your memory... but in addition to that, if you get the files loaded, your code will do 650 000 000 000 times the calculations you have. That's probably going to take a while (if you can do the operations within 1 microsecond, it's going to take a week).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, ok. Let me re-phrase. Please don't use Indian / Pakistani / Burmese or any other South East Asian English words here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "chunksize" option for the dataframe?
It is used to split large datasets into smaller ones if does not fit into memory -
here is a good explanation where they want to read in 10G+ of data into a dataframe: http://acepor.github.io/2017/08/03/using-chunksize/.

You can try the code  below, but I think you need to get the read_csv to work first for your specific file format and find out the column names/numbers.
You can also tune the size of the chunksize; larger is usually faster.
It will still go slow since it's a nested loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

outfile = 'tab1_tab2_match.dat'
df1 = pd.read_csv('tab1.dat', encoding='ascii', chunksize=1)

col1 = 0
col1_1 = 1

col2 = 0
col2_1 = 1

writeheader= True
mode = 'w'

for cm in df1:
    df2 = pd.read_csv('tab2.dat', encoding='ascii', chunksize=100000)
    for chunk in df2:
        chunk.columns = ['col2', 'col2_1' ]
        chunk['del1'] = np.abs(chunk.iloc[:, col1] - cm.iloc[0, col1_1])
        chunk['del2'] = np.abs(chunk.iloc[:, col2] - cm.iloc[0, col2_1])
        chunk['dist'] = np.sqrt((chunk['del1'] * np.cos(chunk['del2'])) ** 2 + chunk['del2'] ** 2)

        tmp = chunk[chunk['dist'] <= 0.00008333]
        tmp['col1', 'col1_2'] = cm.iloc[0, [col1, col1_1]]
        tmp = tmp ['']

        tmp['col2', 'col2_1', 'col1', 'col2_1'].to_csv(outfile, mode=mode, header=writeheader)
        mode = 'a'
        writeheader = False
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Performance, That's the problem with loops and Python. I suggest you to change your method. 
You have two input dataframe : 
-table (col1 col2)
-table1 (col1_1 col2_1)

You want to substract col1 with col1_1 , col2 with col2_1 and compare the values to a threshold d and append the 4 columns inside an output dataframe.

Here is a method without looping, and pandas

```
import pandas as pd 

table = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5], 'col2': [6,7,8,9,10]})
table1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1_1': [0.5, 0.2,0.3,0.9,0.9], 'col2_1': [5.1,5.2,4.5,5.4,8.5]})

print(table)
print(table1)
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
   col1_1  col2_1
0     0.5     5.1
1     0.2     5.2
2     0.3     4.5
3     0.9     5.4
4     0.9     8.5


## 1. Join the 2 tables 
join = table.join(table1)
print(join)
   col1  col2  col1_1  col2_1
0     1     6     0.5     5.1
1     2     7     0.2     5.2
2     3     8     0.3     4.5
3     4     9     0.9     5.4
4     5    10     0.9     8.5



## 2. create a new columns with substraction 
join["del1"] = abs(join['col1'] - join['col1_1'])
join["del2"] = abs(join['col2'] - join['col2_1'])
print(join)
   col1  col2  col1_1  col2_1  del1  del2
0     1     6     0.5     5.1   0.5   0.9
1     2     7     0.2     5.2   1.8   1.8
2     3     8     0.3     4.5   2.7   3.5
3     4     9     0.9     5.4   3.1   3.6
4     5    10     0.9     8.5   4.1   1.5



## 3. filter with threshold 
d = 2 
final_df = join[(join.del1 < d) & (join.del2 <d)]
print(final_df)
   col1  col2  col1_1  col2_1  del1  del2
0     1     6     0.5     5.1   0.5   0.9
1     2     7     0.2     5.2   1.8   1.8
```

Comment: Does OP's code use memory beyond loading the files into lists? It doesn't seem to me. The bottleneck is getting the files into memory which your answer fails to address.

Comment: "Is there any way to run the code faster or any way which I should follow to make this job done? " here is the actual question, so i tried to help about performances

Comment: "As I am running the code, the code terminates because of the huge size files am importing." I don't think OP realized that none of their actual code gets to run.

Comment: Ok you right Andras Deak, 
I've already had hard deals with memory issues and multiple for loops in Python, and one of the way of is to avoid multiple loops on huge dataframe. 
it pains me to have to justify myself so much, while I try to help the PO, I do not think my answer is off topic, it's a try !

Comment: I never said that it's wrong, just that it probably misses the first issue. If they can get it to work then killing the loops is the next step for a finite runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try this way.